# Making an object public static vs passing it around

Tags: c#, monogame

I am writing a game in Monogame framework and well
there are some objects that have only 1 instance 
(but that does not necessarily mean that there should be only 1 
instance) during the lifespan of an application by default,
like for example ContentManager.

Now what's bugging me is that I am not sure what is a better practice and why:

1. To make that object **public static** and access it from other classes
   to use that static instance to load stuff

or

2. Pass that object as an argument to other classes constructor and use it that way

Comment: Sorry - questions like this are opinion-based and therefore off-topic on Stack Overflow. We can help you if you have chosen one option and have problems, but arguably there isn't a right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another option, you can use the singleton pattern to restrict the creation of new classes, like a GameManager. This pattern comes with cons and pros, so you need to analyze your requirements.

```
public final class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

The simplest way to implement the implement the pattern is to have a class with a private constructor, a static parameter for your instance and a method to return the instance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: That's not valid C#. Also OP stated *"some objects that have only 1 instance (but that does not necessarily mean that there should be only 1 instance)"* - which rules out singletons